# How does FormData() knows the path in OS of the file that is submitted in the form?

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data

Here is the dump of the File object that is passed to FormData(). There is no path info. This file is on my Desktop, not in the project folder that this javascript is running.

### [image: > name: "I5CY82H6U7ROL1]@)9D]9)G.jpg" size: 39424 type: "image/jpeg" > webkitRelativePath: "" > __proto__: File]

I am using the following code to submit the form. So how does the program know the path of the file that I am sending in the form? 
The same also confuse me when I am using FileReader instead of the form to get the OS file that user submitted. There is only the file name in the File object.

My question is where is the path info?

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); // number 123456 is immediately converted to string "123456"

// HTML file input user's choice...
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `fileInputElement.files[0]` represent the input of an `input type="file"` element.

The browser is your intermediate between the actual file and the server / client. It reads the bytes from disk and passes it into the steam.

Comment: Can I say the browser knows the local path of the file, javascript asks the content from the browser, and submit the content to the server? But the browser doesn't provide api to reveal the path info?

Comment: You are entirely right. You don't want the server or JavaScript to know the local path. It doesn't matter for them and can cause security issues.

Answer (score 0):

FormData() doesn't know the path to the file and doesn't need to. This functionality is used to upload a file to a web server and the web server does not have access to the user's file system. From the web server's point of view the file is just a string of bytes and the file name is just a reference to what the file should be called.

Answer (score 0):

The information is stored inside the file object, but not exposed to JavaScript through the API.

The browser needs to know where the file is to upload it or to provide access to the data via the FileReader interface, but the JavaScript does not (since it can just ask for the content of the file if it needs it).

Comment: Quentin, how do you know this? Is it possible that you can give me some reference?